# Regex grouping until space

Tags: python, regex

I have a line like this:

```
[24 Mar 2019] ABC-000 somestring-with-numbers-and-dashes - a whole bunch of text
```

The regex is this:

```
re_header = re.compile(r'^\[(\d\d) ([A-Z][a-z][a-z]) (\d{4})\] '
                    + r'(ABC-\d+(?:-\d+)?)\s+'
                    + r'(.*?)\s*$')
```

Now what I get is this:

```
('24', 'Mar', '2019', 'ABC-000', 'somestring-with-numbers-and-dashes - a whole bunch of text')
```

What I want though is an additional group consisting of 'somestring-with-numbers-and-dashes', like this:

```
('24', 'Mar', '2019', 'ABC-000', 'somestring-with-numbers-and-dashes')
```

Everything behind `'somestring-with-numbers-and-dashes'` should be ignored.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Replace your last regex to `(.*?)\s-.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\[(\d{2}) ([A-Z][a-z]{2}) (\d{4})\]\s*(DSA-\d+(?:-\d+)?)\s+([^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9fPvRz/1) (since your pattern contains `DSA` and not `ABC`, I used `DSA` in my pattern and demo string at regex101).

The part you are interested in is `([^\s-]+(?:-[^\s-]+)*)`:

- `[^\s-]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `-`
- `(?:-[^\s-]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `-` followed with any 1+ chars other than whitespace and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change final `(.*?)\s*$` to `([^\s]*)`:

```
re_header = re.compile(r'^\[(\d\d) ([A-Z][a-z][a-z]) (\d{4})\] '
                    + r'(ABC-\d+(?:-\d+)?)\s+'
                    + r'(\S*)')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CAE6yA/1)

Note, I had to change `DSA` to `ABC` in your original expression to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple replace the last regex part to

```
(.*?) - .*$
```

So you capture as little text as possible until the `-` comes.

Answer (score 1):

The other problems in your regex if the date contains only 1 digit and the month is more than 3 characters, eg. 9 June 2019. Also, you use `DSA` in your regex, but how can it be `ABC` in your output? So, to accomodate these, it will be better if you use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/z9nueX/1):

```
^\[(\d+) ([A-Za-z]+) (\d{4})\] ([A-Z]+-\d+(?:-\d+)?)\s+(\S*)
```